# Redirect output from SSH to local TFT screen

Tags: ssh, pitft

I am using my laptop to connect to a RPi using SSH.

But now I would like to display graphics on a (Adafruit 2.8") TFT screen directly connected to the RPI while controlling the RPi via SSH - is this possible?

The reason for this is that the TFT screen is where the graphics will be shown when I am done with the project (SSH is only used for development).

Comment: Please be more clear.  What kind of graphics?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to start a GUI program from remote SSH on your tft ?

Answer (score 1):

Well i would recommend to try setting FRAMEBUFFER correctly, then launching your command with `&` at the end, via ssh.

`command params &`